# Checking if a variable is initialized

Tags: c++, class

Seems like this would be a duplicate, but maybe it is just so obvious it hasn't been asked...

Is this the proper way of checking if a variable (not pointer) is initialized in a C++ class?

```
class MyClass
{
    void SomeMethod();

    char mCharacter;
    double mDecimal;
};

void MyClass::SomeMethod()
{
    if ( mCharacter )
    {
        // do something with mCharacter.
    }

    if ( ! mDecimal )
    {
        // define mDecimal.
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "is defined"? do you mean "has a value" as "initialized"?

Comment: All variables have always a value (they are defined). Normally compilers initialize variables to some standard value, but I am not sure if this is part of the definition of C++, as far as I know it is not. It is a good practice to initialize all variables before using them, so that they never have some random or implementation-dependent value. Then you can check their current value at any time before using them.

Comment: @Jay, you really need to reword your question to match words that C++ uses. According to C++ rules, mCharacter is ALWAYS ALWAYS ALWAYS defined in MyClass in your example. 'char mCharacter' appearing there means it is defined. Now you need to think over what you really need by "is mCharacter defined". Do you mean, "assigned to ?". C++ cannot really check that. "Has value different from initialization value" ? Maybe, but then, your example does not have any initialization value, so you cannot check for that, too, unless you add initializer and constructor. In this form, question must berephrased

Comment: Why do you distinguish pointers? Pointer variables are just variables with a pointer type.

Comment: If you don't want to use boost::optional you can create your own type.. e.g. <int, bool> and set the bool to true when initialised.. although i'd recommend just using boost::optional

Comment: with the advent of C++17 possibility wouldn't be better change the right answer?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

There is no way of checking of the contents of a variable are undefined or not. The best thing you can do is to assign a signal/sentinel value (for example in the constructor) to indicate that further initialization will need to be carried out.

Comment: Unfortunately, this answer is not correct. There _is_ an implementation for class members without using a sentinel value if you consider C++-11, see my answer below.

Comment: @Twonky It's still correct. Using smart pointer or `std::optional` is similar to having a `bool` ("signal") to mark whether the variable is initialized.

Answer (score 25):

Variable that is not defined will cause compilation error.

What you're asking is about checking if it is **initialized**. But initialization is just a value, that you should choose and assign in the constructor.

For example:

```
class MyClass
{
    MyClass() : mCharacter('0'), mDecimal(-1.0){};
    void SomeMethod();

    char mCharacter;
    double mDecimal;
};

void MyClass::SomeMethod()
{
    if ( mCharacter != '0')
    {
        // touched after the constructor
        // do something with mCharacter.
    }

    if ( mDecimal != -1.0 )
    {
        // touched after the constructor
        // define mDecimal.
    }
}
```

You should initialize to a default value that will mean something in the context of your logic, of course.

Comment: Adding to this answer, you can set in the c-tor an invalid value and check if it is still invalid during your method. or using a boolean to flag the value was changed from initial invalid one

Comment: @NirMH I would say almost always if you don't have the information to create a valid object at construction, that constructor should be removed in favor of a constructor with enough information to make a valid object.

Comment: this is exactly what @alexander-gessler meant with his _signal/sentinel value_

Answer (score 21):

**With C++17** you can use [`std::optional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) to check if a variable is initialized:

```
#include <optional>
#include <iostream>  // needed only for std::cout

int main() {
    std::optional<int> variable;

    if (!variable) {
        std::cout << "variable is NOT initialized\n";
    }

    variable = 3;

    if (variable) {
        std::cout << "variable IS initialized and is set to " << *variable << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This will produce the output:

```
variable is NOT initialized
variable IS initialized and is set to 3
```

---

To use `std::optional` in the code snipped you provided, you'll have to include the [`<optional>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/optional) standard library header and add `std::optional<...>` to the respective variable declarations:

```
#include <optional>

class MyClass
{
    void SomeMethod();

    std::optional<char> mCharacter;
    std::optional<double> mDecimal;
};

void MyClass::SomeMethod()
{
    if ( mCharacter )
    {
        std::cout << *mCharacter;  // do something with mCharacter.
    }

    if ( ! mDecimal )
    {
        mDecimal = 3.14159;  // define mDecimal.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 17):

Depending on your applications (and especially if you're already using boost), you might want to look into [`boost::optional`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html).

*(UPDATE: As of C++17, optional is now part of the standard library, as [`std::optional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional))*

It has the property you are looking for, tracking whether the slot actually holds a value or not.  By default it is constructed to not hold a value and evaluate to false, but if it evaluates to true you are allowed to dereference it and get the wrapped value.

```
class MyClass
{
    void SomeMethod();

    optional<char> mCharacter;
    optional<double> mDecimal;
};

void MyClass::SomeMethod()
{
    if ( mCharacter )
    {
        // do something with *mCharacter.
        // (note you must use the dereference operator)
    }

    if ( ! mDecimal )
    {
        // call mDecimal.reset(expression)
        // (this is how you assign an optional)
    }
}
```

More examples are in [the Boost documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/optional/doc/html/boost_optional/examples.html).

Answer (score 4):

There's no reasonable way to check whether a value has been initialized.

If you care about whether something has been initialized, instead of trying to check for it, put code into the constructor(s) to ensure that they are always initialized and be done with it.

Answer (score 4):

With C++-11 or Boost libs you could consider storing the variable using smart pointers. Consider this MVE where `toString()` behaviour depends on `bar` being initialized or not:

```
#include <memory>
#include <sstream>

class Foo {

private:
    std::shared_ptr<int> bar;

public:
    Foo() {}
    void setBar(int bar) {
        this->bar = std::make_shared<int>(bar);
    }
    std::string toString() const {
        std::ostringstream ss;
        if (bar)           // bar was set
            ss << *bar;
        else               // bar was never set
            ss << "unset";
        return ss.str();
    }
};
```

Using this code

```
Foo f;
std::cout << f.toString() << std::endl;
f.setBar(42);
std::cout << f.toString() << std::endl;
```

produces the output

```
unset
42
```

Comment: would this work for a non-pointer variable e.g. `Foo f; if (f) ...` -- it doesn't seem to work for me but maybe there's an other way?

Comment: No, the smart pointers solution only works for pointer variables. If you need to put your variable on the stack, I suggest using Elmar's solution utilizing `std::optional`.

Comment: What is MVE? Minimum Viable Example? Minimum Viable Experiment?

Comment: i think it is not correct cuz smart pointers size are bigger than your variables. it is similar to define flag for your variable and set to true in setter function.

Comment: @Amir: you are right with indicating that the use of smart pointers implies a bigger memory footprint. However, the question did not indicate that memory usage would matter. Many efforts of advanced programming techniques aim at making things happen _automatically_ so there is no chance to forget to do something. Using smart pointers, or `std::optional` as Elmar suggested, asserts that you may always check if the variable indicated. There is simply no chance to forget using the flag you indicated. Plus: no need to enforce the use of setters instead of accessing the variable directly.

Answer (score 3):

By default, no you can't know if a variable (or pointer) has or hasn't been initialized. However, since everyone else is telling you the "easy" or "normal" approach, I'll give you something else to think about. Here's how you *could* keep track of something like that (no, I personally would never do this, but perhaps you have different needs than me).

```
class MyVeryCoolInteger
{
public:
    MyVeryCoolInteger() : m_initialized(false) {}

    MyVeryCoolInteger& operator=(const int integer)
    {
        m_initialized = true;
        m_int = integer;
        return *this;
    }

    int value()
    {
        return m_int;
    }

    bool isInitialized()
    {
        return m_initialized;
    }

private:
    int m_int;
    bool m_initialized;
};
```

Comment: Your very cool integer exists, more abstractly as a template, and is called `boost::optional`.  (See my answer.)  Nothing wrong with using it if that's the kind of situation you've got.  Though certainly if you have millions of integers, it might well pay to pick one magic value to indicate "no value".

Comment: Oh no doubt. But as mentioned, I thought I'd give an alternative answer.

Answer (score 2):

Since `MyClass` is a POD class type, those non-static data members will have indeterminate initial values when you create a non-static instance of `MyClass`, so no, that is not a valid way to check if they have been initialized to a specific non-zero value ... you are basically assuming they will be zero-initialized, which is not going to be the case since you have not value-initialized them in a constructor.

If you want to zero-initialize your class's non-static data members, it would be best to create an initialization list and class-constructor.  For example:

```
class MyClass
{
    void SomeMethod();

    char mCharacter;
    double mDecimal;

    public:
        MyClass();
};

MyClass::MyClass(): mCharacter(0), mDecimal(0) {}
```

The initialization list in the constructor above value-initializes your data-members to zero.  You can now properly assume that any non-zero value for `mCharacter` and `mDecimal` must have been specifically set by you somewhere else in your code, and contain non-zero values you can properly act on.

Comment: Member variables are not initialized to default or random values when the object is instantiated **unless** it is explicitly done in the c-tor. Many debug runtimes will initialize the memory to a specific value when it is allocated (new), otherwise it's UB and the value will be whatever the memory contained prior to instantiation.

Comment: The default constructor for `MyClass`, since it does not value-initialize any variables in the OP's original version, will create random values for the data members ... a random value (i.e., the value already existing in memory) is the default-initialization for a POD data-type.

Comment: "default-initialized with random values" - This statement implies that by default some type of initialization occurs which stores a random value in the variable. The correct term is simply "uninitialized"

Comment: I really didn't mean to sound like such a nazi about it ;)

Answer (score 2):

If you mean how to check whether member variables have been initialized, you can do this by assigning them sentinel values in the constructor. Choose sentinel values as values that will never occur in normal usage of that variable. If a variables entire range is considered valid, you can create a boolean to indicate whether it has been initialized.

```
#include <limits>

class MyClass
{
    void SomeMethod();

    char mCharacter;
    bool isCharacterInitialized;
    double mDecimal;

    MyClass()
    : isCharacterInitialized(false)
    , mDecimal( std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN() )
    {}


};


void MyClass::SomeMethod()
{
    if ( isCharacterInitialized == false )
    {
        // do something with mCharacter.
    }

    if ( mDecimal != mDecimal ) // if true, mDecimal == NaN
    {
        // define mDecimal.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no way in the C++ language to check whether a variable is initialized or not (although class types with constructors will be initialized automatically).

Instead, what you need to do is provide constructor(s) that initialize your class to a valid state. Static code checkers (and possibly some compilers) can help you find missing variables in constructors. This way you don't *have* to worry about being in a bogus state and the `if` checks in your method can go away completely.

Answer (score 0):

If you donot like boost and c++17, the google c++ lib [Abseil](https://abseil.io/) is another method to realize that. absl::optional is  just like std::optional.

```
#include <absl/types/optional.h>
class MyClass
{
    void SomeMethod();

    absl::optional<char> mCharacter;
    absl::optional<double> mDecimal;
};

void MyClass::SomeMethod()
{
    if (mCharacter)
    {
        // do something with mCharacter.
    }

    if (!mDecimal)
    {
        // define mDecimal.
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could reference the variable in an assertion and then build with `-fsanitize=address`:

```
void foo (int32_t& i) {
    // Assertion will trigger address sanitizer if not initialized:
    assert(static_cast<int64_t>(i) != INT64_MAX);
}
```

This will cause the program to reliably crash with a stack trace (as opposed to undefined behavior).