# Variable not initialized as condition c++

Tags: c++, if-statement

I want to do an if like:

```
if(x has not been initialized)
{...
}
```

Is this possible? Thanks

Comment: No, it's not. That's why it's best to initialize all your variables at the point of declaration. (in the standard meaning of the work "initialize"). You can of course design your class and define "initialization" as "after you call `Init()`, but that's different.

Comment: If you need this kind of thing, maybe look at [`boost::optional`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html) or C++14 [`std::optional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional).

Comment: What is the storage duration of `x`? If it's static, then it is entirely possible.

Comment: Just curious on what are we trying to achieve to check if x is initialized or not. Please update the thread if you have an problem statement.

Comment: Thanks all but I've already solved my problem. There is a better choice than do this if..

Comment: C++ it is difficult for interpretive like perl you can check if variable is initialized or not ...in ruby all variables are nil if not initialized..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Checking if a variable is initialized](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822044/checking-if-a-variable-is-initialized)

Answer (score 4):

*"There is no way of checking of the contents of a variable are undefined or not. The best thing you can do is to assign a signal/sentinel value (for example in the constructor) to indicate that further initialization will need to be carried out."*

[Alexander Gessler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/234053/alexander-gessler)

from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822044/c-checking-if-a-variable-is-initialized?answertab=active#tab-top)

Answer (score 3):

To implement that behavior you may use pointers, default initiated to 0.

For example:

```
int *number = 0;
// ...
if (!number) {
    // do something
}
```

You may use that trick with any types, not just integers:

```
Cat *kitty = 0;
// ...
if (!kitty) {
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

a) For primitive datatypes such as int, float its not possible to know if its initialized or not.

b) For pointers you can check if its not nullptr or not

```
if(ptr != nullptr)
{
}
```

c) For custom class you need to introduce bool member which can be set to true in constructor so that we can use it to check if object is initialized or not.

```
if(obj.isInitialized())
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

- If you have a pointer, you can use `nullptr` to denote "not initialized."
- If you have a non-pointer, you can use `boost::optional<T>` (or `std::optional<T>` when it becomes available).
- Otherwise, the naive "`bool initialized;`" flag will have to do. `optional<T>` is basically just encapsulating this flag.

Answer (score 0):

With C++-11 you could consider storing the variable using smart pointers. Declare yor variable `x` (assuming x to be `int`) as

```
std::shared_ptr<int> x;
```

When assigning your variable `x`, use

```
x = std::make_shared<int>(newValueOfX);
```

and then you may determine if `x` was ever assigned by checking

```
if (this->x) { ... }
```

See [Checking if a variable is initialized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822044/checking-if-a-variable-is-initialized/41893384#41893384) for a more detailed example.

Answer (score -1):

Well something like that would work for pointers.  Say:

```
int* x = NULL;  //initialize
if(x == NULL)
{
    //dostuff
}
```

or simply

```
if(!x)
{
    //dostuff
}
```

Not sure if there is a way for just regular int's though

EDIT: Now that I think about it, Luthian is right.  That would be undefined behavior.  As the rest have said you must initialize to some known value.

Comment: No. That's undefined behavior. Outside a debug build (arguably), `x` will most probably not be initialized to `NULL`.

Comment: Yea, you are right @LuchianGrigore now that I think about it.